# Zapier - Remove item from Line-Items object and/or output Line-items from Code step

Tags: zapier

it's been several times that I got stuck with this one: I don't understand how to output Line-Items with a Code step?

Is it even possible?

For example:

- I build Line-Items from a JSON
- In these Line-Items, I would like to remove some of them, based on various criteria
- Then output Line-Items and use them in a further step

[Here is something I tried](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vw9Oj.png)

[But, on a further step, I don't get Line-Items but separate values.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SGsfs.png)

So, how to manipulate Line-Items into a Code step and get Line-Items as the output?

I feel like I'm missing something...

Thanks.

PS: more explanation on the "why".

I got my data from a Typeform entry in which I can get between 1 and 5 emails (plus other data)
So, I got empty row that I want to remove
That's why I build a Line-Items object then try to remove the useless ones

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you're looking for, but this is what I use. Given two line items, one with names and one with values, each separated by ;;, I combine those into one object, and then use the value of a field based on the name in a later action.

```
var names = inputData.names.split(";;");
var values = inputData.values.split(";;");

function toObject(names, values) {
    var result = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < names.length; i++)
         result[names[i]] = values[i];
    return result;
}

output = toObject(names,values);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Yeah it's the right way to do it, I had nearly the same answer from Zapier Community https://community.zapier.com/developer-discussion-13/remove-item-from-line-items-object-and-or-output-line-items-from-code-step-852

Zapier Support also answered the same thing!